# Does a city I have liberated still exert loyalty pressure on me?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

Does liberating a city stop loyalty pressure both directions? (When you liberate a city it says you will not influence their city anymore) so naturally I want to know if his city can actually cause MY city to rebel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect is not reciprocal. In the image below you will see that I liberated a city for the Polish only to have my Loyalty Pressure completely negated and theirs remain intact. So yes it is possible for a city that you have liberated to flip one of your cities later on.

[image]

Comment: I feel like liberating an english city is a pretty bad idea.